# Cannot find replacement for Event onAfterFilterChanged in ag-grid version 19

Tags: ag-grid

In ag-Grid version 9, we used event onAfterFilterChanged to update totals of floatingTopRow when filter was applied on any column.
Now when upgrading to version 19, event onAfterFilterChanged cannot be found. Please can anyone tell me the replacement event for this in ag-Grid version 19.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filterChanged` event for the same.

Reference: [Sort & Filter](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#sort-filter)

> filterChanged:    Filter has modified and applied.

More reference for **[Event Properties & Hierarchy](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-events/#properties-and-hierarchy)**

Comment: (Sorry for stupid question but i am new to this)
onAfterFilterChanged?(event?: any): void;, here we passed input parameter as any, for onFilterChanged?(event: FilterChangedEvent): void;
Input parameter is of type FilterChangedEvent, from which name space to import this?

Comment: Also, please can you read this link - https://github.com/ag-grid/ag-grid/issues/2301 seems some issue with filterChanged event

Comment: 1. namespace `ag-grid-community`. 2. its a `feature request`, not an issue.

Comment: you can upvote the answer, it is helpful to you. mark it as answer, if it answers your question.

Comment: How to update to answer, yes some of your comments were v helpful.

Comment: the `up` button above `0` (vote count) on the left side of the answer. FYI: It depends on your reputation. Go through [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) of [so] for better understanding and get familiarity with the community.

Comment: I have reputation of only 9, no up button :(
Also i tried onFilterChanged but it removes the menuContext besides the columns, it only shows filter option. We had a menuContext coming earlier